# Does ES6 support spread syntax like { a as a1 } = obj or is there an RFC on that?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So consider the following snippet

```
const x = {
     name: 'somebody'
};

const { name as somePerson } = x;  // Would be awesome to have something like this
```

Comment: Side note: The JavaScript specification doesn't have RFCs (that I know of). There's this thing called the TC39 committee that has a standard process for approving proposals to the ECMAScript language specification.

Comment: You should always refer to **[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)** first. They usually have solution for most common problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could change the target in the [Object Property Assignment Pattern [You Don't Know JS: ES6 & Beyond, Chapter 2: Syntax]](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#object-property-assignment-pattern):

> The syntactic pattern here is `source: target` (or `value: variable-alias`).

```
{ name: somePerson }
```

```js
const x = {
     name: 'somebody'
};

const { name: somePerson } = x;

console.log(somePerson);
```